# batch send "ENTER" key to running program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have an "old-good" `fortran.exe` file (without access to the code) and I need to execute a few hundred times using a batch file.

However, at the end of the fortran program, it prints `"Press ENTER to exit"`, interrupting, of course, the execution of the batch file...

Is there a way to send the `{ENTER}` to the running program?

Comment: this really has nothing to do with fortran and is specific to your system/shell.  I guess this is a windows question but you might want to say so and add appropriate tags

Comment: I agree! Removed the fortran and added windows and cmd tags. Thanks

Comment: Try `echo/|fortran.exe`. May work or not - depends on how the fortran programmer implemented the request.

Comment: Do you have to use a batch file? PowerShell could probably work?

Answer (score 3):

check the [sendkeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat). The script is capable to send a keys to running program with particular title:

```
call sendkeys.bat "fortran-program" "{ENTER}"
```

**EDIT**

[try with this script](https://gist.github.com/npocmaka/235c274d06219dea1b5a8f45e646716f)

```
call nonsecureSendKeys.bat "progfortr" "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: seems interesting, but it says "failed to find application with title progfortr.exe" ...

Comment: @JoãoPalma - try without `.exe` suffix

Comment: @JoãoPalma - you need the string in the title bar

Comment: same problem using:
`call sendkeys.bat "progfortr.exe" "{ENTER}"`
`call sendkeys.bat "progfortr" "{ENTER}"`
`call sendkeys.bat progfortr.exe "{ENTER}"`
`call sendkeys.bat progfortr "{ENTER}"`

what do you mean by "need the string in the title bar" ?

Comment: @JoãoPalma - (window components)[http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-RF7v_-DheWc/UWuu435LqgI/AAAAAAAABGI/fnO8RgEDdSk/s1600/01-Word+2007+Interface.png]  .Anyway... Is the focus switched the the fortran program?

Comment: Liked the "window components for dummies" :) but did not understand your question, i.e. if I run the batfile.bat file, the title will be "path\to\cmd.exe -batfile.bat" . But to have the focus switched to the fortran, I have to execute the fortran separately from the bat file. Even so, having two windows opened, when I run the fortran program and leave it hanged in the "press enter to continue" message, and in the other window execute the batfile.bat, it says the same "Failed to find application..." but then, interestingly, it switches focus to the fortran program... but it does nothing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108669/discussion-between-joao-palma-and-npocmaka).

Comment: @JoãoPalma  - check my edit.Looks like there's a problem with `AppActivate` function.

Comment: Ok. With the edited version it works having two shells opened. One previously with the fortran program and the other where the bat file is run. 
does this means I can not do this with one single bat file that 1)calls/starts the fortran program and 2) send the ENTER key in the same bat file?

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem recently and this is the easiest/fastest working solution I found:

```
echo & echo.|fortran.exe
```

You pipe-in "& echo." (new line) inside the keyboard buffer, waiting to be consumed by the executable.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work for the no windowed programs.

Because you should do This : `.AppActivate(title).`

For the programs run without any window,you can't activate it.